# Clearing a tkinter root.subform from within a separate function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have several larger `tkinter` / `python` program which I would like to incorporate into one program which would clear a frame when another program is called; each program currently being inside a function (I probably should use classes eventually when I understand them) and each of these function being displayed on a form being cleared of widgets from the previous if any do exist.

The code below is just a small trial for me to understand how to do this, but it's not working.

When I invoke the widget.destroy() function, it removes the frame (DisplayFrame) and does not clear the widgets inside it and hence not displaying the new widgets.

here is the current trial code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#import pandas as pd
import MultiTempsP3
import datetime, time

from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
from tkinter import colorchooser
from configparser import ConfigParser

import os
import csv

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == "":
    print('no display found.Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY',':0.0')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Kombucha Program")
root.geometry("1400x800")
root.minsize(width=900, height=600)
    #root.maxsize(width=1400, height = 900)
root.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.configure( bg = '#000080' )

DisplayFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=1200, height = 630, bg = 'yellow')       #0059b3')
DisplayFrame.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky = N, in_ = root)

rightFrame = tk.Frame(root, width = 120, height = 390, bg = 'white') # #000080
rightFrame.grid(column = 1, row = 0, pady = 10, padx = 10)

lblFrame = tk.Frame(root, height = 70, width = 670, bg = 'black')
lblFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky =N, in_ = root)

##'W' stands for West = WrightFrmae (west fframe on the right of screen
#WrightFrame = tk.Frame(rightFrame, width = 70, height = 300, bg = 'green') #  #000080
#WrightFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

WidgetFrame = tk.Frame(root, height = 300, width = 120, bg = 'red') # #000080
WidgetFrame.grid(column=0,row=2, pady = 30)

fromTemp =  MultiTempsP3.temps("65cd6bd")
lblTemp = Label(rightFrame, text=fromTemp).grid(row=1,column=0,pady=0 )
#lblTemp.pack()

def clearDisplayFrame():
    for widgets in DisplayFrame.winfo_children():
        widgets.destroy()
        
###***### - This section is in the right top little frame = rightFrame
state = "yes" ## delete this row and use below state=GPIO when on an RPi
#state = GPIO.input(17)
if state:
    state_17="GPIO_17 (HeatPad) is On "
else:
    state_17="GPIO_17 (HeatPad) is Off "
lblHeatPad = Label(rightFrame, text=state).grid(row=3,column=0,pady=0 ) #shows as text in the window
#lblHeatPad.pack() #organizes widgets in blocks before placing them in the parent.          
###***### End of rightFrame widgets



def func_quit():
    root.destroy()



def openData():
    clearDisplayFrame()
    print("I am inside openData()")
    lbltrial=tk.Label(DisplayFrame,text="trial").grid(row=3, column=2)
    
def func_Temps():
    clearDisplayFrame()
    print("I am inside func_Temps()")
    
    #DisplayFrame = tk.Frame(root, width=1200, height = 630, bg = 'yellow')       #0059b3')
    #DisplayFrame.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky = N, in_ = root)    
    lblSomething = tk.Label(DisplayFrame, text = "Open Temps").grid(row=2,column=2)
    

###***### This section is top of left = lblFrame

exitButton = tk.Button(lblFrame, text="Quit the Program",  width = 12, command=root.destroy, bg= "magenta")
exitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 1, pady = 5, padx = 5)
dataButton = Button(lblFrame, text="Open Dates Window", command=openData).grid(row=0, column=1)  ## the open refers to the above function
tempsButton= Button(lblFrame, text="Open Temps Info", command=func_Temps).grid(row=0, column=2)
###***### End of top left widget in lblFrame


mainloop()
```

Comment: `for widgets in DisplayFrame.winfo_children(): widget.destroy()` in `clearDisplayFrame`, did you mean to use `widgets.destroy()` or `for widget ...`? but more so how does that not raise an exception because you haven't defined `widget` anywhere

Comment: You are correct, it should be widgets.destroy() instead of widget.destroy(). I corrected this above and in my local code.

Comment: As I tried if again with the above correction (widget to widgets) it still has the main problem of removing the frame DisplayFrame

Comment: you want to remove the frame or all widgets inside? because the code clearly removes the widgets inside

Comment: I would like to only remove the widgets, not the frame. I made the separate frames drastically different colors to know if frames are present for this trial. The DisplayFrame is bright yellow - using the above clearDisplayFrame() function (utilizing widgets.destroy) it removes the DisplayFrame and places the labels on the blue (root) background - the frames on the side then being pusched to the center of the window

Comment: IMO the best way is to make more than one frame for different window(scenarios), then keep raising the frames, IIRC using `tk_raise()` method for frame

Comment: oh, I see, `DisplayFrame` is obviously not destroyed (because never is `destroy` called on it), it just shrinks to fit its widgets, at start it doesn't have any so it is set to its width and height, but as soon as you add any widgets, it shrinks to fit them, add `DisplayFrame.grid_propagate(False)` somewhere after assigning `DisplayFrame = tk.Frame(...)` so that the frame doesn't shrink to fit its contents, but even better is if you follow @CoolCloud advice and use separate frames

Comment: That was it!!! TY tons! How can I mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: it's a comment so you can't mark it as accepted answer, but it's fine, I also would need to clarify that using multiple frames won't fix this specific issue as they will still shrink to fit their content (unless you specify otherwise with `_propagate`) but you won't have to destroy all widgets in a frame to show new widgets, you will just need to switch out the frames (which is what you will do anyways once you go for an OOP approach)

Comment: And TY again!!! I have already started with a 2 frame approach as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer, here is an approach that uses 2 frame and switches between them in the click of the switch. This is the way usually switching between frame is implemented in procedural programming, AFAIK:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def change(frame):
    frame.tkraise() # Raising the passed frame

window1 = Frame(root)
window2 = Frame(root)

window1.grid(row=0,column=0) # Grid in the same location so one will cover/hide the other
window2.grid(row=0,column=0)

# Contents inside your frame...
Label(window1,text='This is page 1',font=(0,21)).pack()
Label(window2,text='This is page 2',font=(0,21)).pack()

# Buttons to switch between frame by passing the frame as an argument
Button(root,text='Page 1',command=lambda: change(window1)).grid(row=1,column=0,stick='w')
Button(root,text='Page 2',command=lambda: change(window2)).grid(row=1,column=0,stick='e')

root.mainloop()
```

So instead of destroying all the items inside your frame, you should just raise the other frame, as destroyed widgets cannot be brought back.